# How to test a function with in a function in phpunittest that declared as private in the class?

Tags: php, laravel, function, testing, phpunit

Need to mock two functions within a class ,one is declared as public and another one is private.

Eg:

```php
class Name {
    public function foo()
    {
        $res = $this->bar($arguments);
        $return = $res;
    }

    private function bar($args)
    {
        //Do some coding
        return something;
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to _test_ them, or _mock_ them? And either way you only need to do that via the public interface.

Comment: `bar` can be considered as implementation detail. So you can just test the `foo` method with the known input and assert that it matches to your expectations.